# Retrofit 2 RequestBody JsonArray

Tags: android, retrofit

How can I put a `JSONArray` into a `RequestBody` without a runtime exception being thrown?

```
@Multipart 
@POST("/call_method")
Call<MyResponse> callMethod(@Part("token")RequestBody token,@Part("params")RequestBody params);
```

I need to put `JSONArray` into params. What I currently do:

```
callMethod(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), token),
           RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), jsonArrayParams));
```

But when I execute this method, I'll get a runtime exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line
```

And very intersting: The request is executed (check via CharlesProxy) but I can't see it result due to the runtime exception.
How can I fix this bug?

Comment: the execution is fine, your problem is in the response, as you declared receiving an object while you are getting Array as response `Call<MyResponse>` ... should be changed to receive array (parsed from response JSON)

Comment: Check response via Postman - I get JSONObject in response and in MyResponse declare single object.

Comment: When I try put JSONObject - execution is fine,but server isn't receive JSONObject, only JSONArray

Comment: @Yazan You are right. I'm was inattentive and noticed square brackets...

Comment: good to hear that, i have posted a full answer if you chose to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the execution is fine, your problem is in the response,

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

as you declared receiving an object `Call<MyResponse>` while you are receiving an Array

you need to change the Type in the callback as following

```
Call<MyResponse[]> callMethod(@Part("token")RequestBody token,@Part("params")RequestBody params);
```

OR

```
Call<List<MyResponse>> callMethod(@Part("token")RequestBody token,@Part("params")RequestBody params);
```